# How to call router level middleware conditionally?

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I have two functions to validate the request body, `validation1` and `validation2`.
Now my task is, after parsing the incoming request body,
I need to validate the data with `validation1` if the user role is `premium user`, otherwise I will validate the data using `validation2`.

I have tried to solve it like the following but to no avail. For some reason, the validation middlewares are not getting called.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
   
const { userController } = require('./controllers');

router.route('/check').post(
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.role === 'premium user') {
      validation1(someInformation);
    } else {
      validation2(someInformation);
    }
    next();
  },
  userController.check
);


const validation1 = (someInformation) => (req, res, next) => {
  // codes
  return next();
}

const validation2 = (someInformation) => (req, res, next) => {
  // codes
  return next();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the `next()` in your `router.route('/check').post(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass callback function `next` to validate function.

Also change your validation function like below code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
   
const { userController } = require('./controllers');

router.route('/check').post(
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.role === 'premium user') {
      validation1(req, res, next);
    } else {
      validation2(req, res, next);
    }
  },
  userController.check
);


const validation1 = (req, res, next) => {
  // codes
  return next();
}

const validation2 = (req, res, next) => {
  // codes
  return next();
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code a bit. Can you please check my code again?

Comment: `validation1` and `validation2` are your functions, you may pass any number of arguments. If you need to pass a few more arguments then you can pass during calling like `validation1(someInformation, req, res, next);`  and accept when you define like `const validation1 = (someInformation, req, res, next) => {`

Comment: Why create function like that `const validation1 = (someInformation) => (req, res, next) =>`? If create function like that, you have two call function twice `validation1(someInformation)(req, res, next)`